# What is Weaviate scoring approach?

Tags: cosine-similarity, scoring, weaviate

I observed that Weaviate score isn't the same as cosine similarity. I'd appreciate it if you could give any resources on Weaviate's scoring approach.

Answer (score 0):

`cosine_sim = 2*certainty - 1` also see [this](https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/current/more-resources/faq.html#q-how-do-i-get-the-cosine-similarity-from-weaviates-certainty) link in Weaviate's FAQ